# Azure Logic App - Dynamic API Connection

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to dynamically choose the FTP API connection that I want to use?
We have defined two FTP API connections in the same resource group, with name ftptest1 and ftptest2.

How can I select one of these in the code view of the Logic App?
I'm only able to select the connection in the designer and then connection 'ftp' is created. See code snippet below.

But I need to dynamically select one of the two FTP connections based on a parameter.

```
"inputs": {
            "body": "@body('XMLFile')",
            "host": {
                "api": {
                    "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net/apim/ftp"
                },
                "connection": {
                     "name": "@parameters('$connections')['ftp']['connectionId']"
                }
            },
```

Is it possible to change the *"@parameters('$connections')['ftp']['connectionId']"* and select an existing API Connection there by name or something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should add a condition after which there will two FTP connectors each using different connection. This should make it dynamic. There is no charge on how many actions are in the definition. We charge on the basis of action execution which in this case will be counted one (either ftp1 or ftp2).

Comment: Well, it depends on the customer deployment how many different FTP locations we could have.
One scenario we have 2, another we have 3, etc. 

It seems to me, that instead of looking up the connectionId in the $connections parameter, it should also be possible to directly fill the "name": property of the api connection?