# Azure logic app without connection

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

There are certain connectors in Logic app (e.g. Outlook Connector) such connectors needs to establish a connection before creating a logic app.

But what if I want to make connection from different account on every request? e.g. Create task On post call I want to create a task in users outlook. I created connector from 1@office.com, then every post request will create task in outlook of 1@office.com even if request coming from 2@office.com

Is there any way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Is the number of different accounts fixed? How many different accounts do you want to use?
The Outlook connector requires to be authenticated per user. But if you can preprovision your API connections, then you could select them dynamically at run time. 
This other thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720265/azure-logic-app-dynamic-api-connection) might shed some light on what you can do for this particular connector.

Answer (score 1):

1) you create a ARM template that deploys a Logic Apps (with all associated API Connections) to a given resource group.

2) This ARM template would have parameters for username and password required for the API connection (e.g. Dropbox).

3) As part of your onboarding (e.g. sign up web site, installer MSI), you would need to request username and password for this user (and sometimes give permission to logic apps to access the resource).

4) Step 3 would create the API Connection with the required authorization, then the logic app could be deployed pointing to that API connection.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates) gives you the basic of ARM provision for Logic Apps.

Including an excellent blog by Kent to add value to this answer, please check "[Custom connectors in Azure Logic App](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/custom-connectors-in-azure-logic-apps?utm_source=StackOverflow&utm_medium=posts&utm_campaign=azure-logic-app-without-connection)"

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to look into creating your own custom web api/custom connector and then you can integrate that with your Logic App.

With your own code you can then dynamically connect as various users to Exchange and automate task creation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app